# Spring AOP does not run as expected

Tags: spring-boot, spring-aop, aspect

I have created a Spring-Boot application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@Slf4j
public class AOPTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AOPTestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have defined an annotation @Parameter to be placed before an argument

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface Parameter {
}
```

In order to handle such an annotation with Spring AOP, I have created an aspect as a component

```
@Component 
@Aspect 
@Slf4j
public class ParameterAspect {

    @Around("execution(* *(.., @Parameter (java.lang.String), ..))")
    public Object executeMethodWithParameterArg(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {

        log.warn("Method " + point.toShortString() + " has been intercepted");

        return point.proceed();
    }
}
```

Now, I have defined two use cases :

1. I call an endpoint which calls a service (where @Parameter is defined)
2. I call an endpoint which calls a local methods (where @Parameter is defined)

Now the RestController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/parameter/test")
@Slf4j
public class ParameterTestRestController {

    @Autowired
    private ParameterService parameterService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void test_1() {
        String arg1 = "ARG1";
        String arg2 = "ARG2";
        log.warn("(BEFORE CALL) ARG1 = " + arg1 + ", ARG2 = " + arg2);
        parameterService.test(arg1, arg2);
    }    

    @RequestMapping(value = "/2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void test_2() {
        String arg1 = "ARG1";
        String arg2 = "ARG2";
        log.warn("(BEFORE CALL) ARG1 = " + arg1 + ", ARG2 = " + arg2);
        test_2(arg1, arg2);
    }

    public void test_2(String arg1, @Parameter String arg2) {
        log.warn("(INSIDE METHOD) ARG1 = " + arg1 + ", ARG2 = " + arg2);
    }
}
```

And the service

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class ParameterService {

    public void test(@Parameter String arg1, String arg2) {
        log.warn("(INSIDE METHOD) ARG1 = " + arg1 + ", ARG2 = " + arg2);
    }
}
```

The method test_1() is well handled by the aspect. But the method test_2() is not.

Why ?

Comment: Spring uses proxies for AOP only method calls into the object are intercepted not internal/local method calls.

Comment: Useful to know. Many thanks.